# Найти количество нулей в записи чисел от 1 до n

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Дано натуральное число n. Требуется найти кол-во цифр '0', встретившихся в записи чисел от 1 до n, n <= 10^16. Очевидно, тривиальный алгоритм будет работать долго.

Comment: Очень не помешало бы несколько тестовых примеров (входные/выходные данные). И что сами думаете по этому поводу? Как пытались решать?

Comment: @MiloserdOFF, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, переоткрыл, т.к задачка на самом деле какая-то головоломная.

--

Понятно, что надо считать количество десятков, сотен, тысяч и т.д и соответствующих остатков в `n` и понятно, что это делается в цикле

    while (n / 10) {
      dr[k] = n % 10;
      nn /= 10;
      dd[k++] = n;
    }

а вот потом... что-то не складываются они правильно.

Может Вам эта формула очевидна?

Тогда поделитесь (невзирая на *учебное задание*).

Comment: @eicto, нужно посчитать количество нулей не в N, а во всех числах от 1 до N. И, очевидно, что решение "в лоб" не сработает при больших N.

Comment: я уже понял, там прогрессия какая-то.

Comment: @avp, эта формула очевидна, но не работает с 4х-значными числами
@ReinRaus, хорошо, учту в следующих вопросах, извините

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как и для большинства олимпиадных задач, для этой нашлось довольно короткое и быстрое решение. Решил ее так: рассматривал заданное число N по цифрам от младших разрядов к старшим. На каждом шаге имеются:

- цифра в текущем разряде
- число - младшие разряды (все что справа от текущей позиции)
- число - старшие разряды (все что слева от текущей позиции)

**1)** Для первого разряда верно утверждение, что `0` там будет встречаться ровно такое число раз, которое осталось в старших разрядах. Т.е. для числа `234`, `0` в разрядах единиц будет встречаться `23` раза, для `105` - `10` раз и т.д.

**2)** Для остальных разрядов (десятки, сотни, тысячи и т.д.) нужно рассмотреть два случая - когда цифра больше нуля и когда она равна нулю:

- Когда цифра в разряде больше нуля, то логика практически такая же как и для первого разряда: На этой позиции `0` будет встречаться ровно такое число раз, которое осталось в старших разрядах, но умноженное на `10` в степени текущего разряда. Поясню на примере: число `123`. На позиции двойки `0` будет встречаться `1 * 10 = 10` раз - для чисел `100` - `109`. Или, число `2308`: на позиции тройки `0` будет встречаться `2 * 100 = 200` раз. Это числа `1000-1099` и `2000-2099`.
- Когда цифра в разряде равна нулю, то НЕВЕРНО утверждать, что `0` в ней встретиться столько раз, сколько было в предыдущем случае (когда цифра не равна нулю). Сейчас он там встретится меньшее число раз. Опять сразу перейду к примеру: число `201`. сколько раз `0` будет стоять в разряде десятков? Ответ - `12`. Это числа `100-109`, `200` и `201`. Так как же получить это число?.. Для этого нужно из числа в старших разрядах вычесть единицу, умножить его на 10 в степени текущего разряда и прибавить к этому произведению число в младших разрядах. И еще добавить единицу. Т.е. для приведенного выше числа `201` это будет `1 * 10 + 1 + 1 = 12`. Дополнительная единица нужна, чтобы не потерять число, когда младшие разряды равно нулю, это `200` в данном случае. (Долго шел к этому пункту, и извиняюсь за невнятное объяснение. Кому будет проще, то это действие у меня вызывает аналогию с вычитанием в столбик, когда вычитаемое содержит нули)

Ну и собственно, реализация алгоритма:

```
int rank = 1;   // Номер разряда (начинаем с младших)
long res = 0;   // Результат
long high = N;  // Число в старших разрядах (изначально равно N)
long low = 0;   // Число в младших разрядах (изначально равно 0)

while (high > 0)
{
    long digit = high % 10;  // Текущая цифра
    high = high / 10;        // Уменьшаем число в старших разрядах

    if (rank > 1 && digit == 0)
    {
        res += ((high - 1) * rank) + (low + 1);  // Случай 2.2
    }
    else
    {
         res += high * rank;  // Случаи 1 и 2.1
    }

    low += rank * digit;  // Увеличиваем число в младших разрядах
    rank *= 10;           // Переходим к следующему разряду
}

// output res
```

Comment: Наивно считать такую задачу олимпиадной. Это не особо сложная комбинаторика, доступная внимательному ученику средних способностей. Кстати, задача решается проще.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi , тут важен уровень олимпиады. На международные и даже уровня страны не тянет, но для отбора кандидатов на уровне городов/регионов - вполне. Давно это было, но с удовольствием гляну на ваше решение.

Comment: Посмотрев повнимательнее на формулировку (*n* — не обязательно степень десяти) и предложенное решение (цикл только по разрядам, т. е. O(log *n*)), я понял, что существенных улучшений не предложу. Разве что напишу более красивые формулы, где будет яснее, что откуда берётся.